# Unable to change shared material of a Gameobject at Runtime, despite being able to locate it via script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

As the title says, I have looked through several posts and have not been able to do this successfully. Basically I have an object with several floors that have certain color codes assosciated with them. I would like to try to change the material using a scripted method using an on click listener. The problem seems to be the actual swapping from old material to new material. I know it it possible since I am able to do so using the inspector. The first thing I tried was setting the instance of .materials (there are 3 materials for each GO) equal to a new array of materials. did not work. Then, I tried the following using SharedMaterials:

```
  Material newMaterial = Resources.Load<Material>("Residential");
  MeshRenderer meshRenderer = GameObject.Find("Level #" + (levels.Count - 1 - i) + "/Group1/Group2/Mesh1").GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
  Material oldMaterial = meshRenderer.sharedMaterials[1];

  Debug.Log("Applied material: " + oldMaterial.name);
  meshRenderer.sharedMaterials[1] = newMaterial;

  Debug.Log("Change Finished.");
```

And here is the console log, showing it at least recognizes the right GO and component and element:

[image]

When I Debug.Log the "new applied material"

```
            Debug.Log("New Applied material: " + meshRenderer.sharedMaterials[1].name);
```

The same (old) material from before the swap is returned.

Any ideas on why it is not resetting the material(s)? I realize using shared materials results in a permanent change which is ok for now, I'd rather have some sort of change than no change at all.

Thank you for your suggestions!!!!

Comment: Read this: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-sharedMaterials.html .  Notice that it says "Note that like all arrays returned by Unity, this [.sharedMaterials] returns a copy of materials array."

Comment: As a followup, try 'meshRenderer.materials[0] = newMaterial;'

Comment: Note that [UnityScript](https://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/UnityScript_versus_JavaScript) is a JavaScript derivative made for Unity. UnityScript != C#. Please do not tag both.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the help John ReinstateMonica!